# Meaning of "born fast" and "stays fast"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

What is means of that expressions? I can't translate, without correct meaning of it.

**Born fast**

**Stays fast**

Huawei use the expressions in a [web site](http://consumer.huawei.com/en/phones/mate10-pro/) advertising a new mobile phone.

[image: Screenshot of Hauwei website]

Comment: It does seem that the words *born, stays* and *fast* have their normal meaning of "created, remains" and "rapid".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's describing a phone. The phone is claimed to be "born fast," which means that it was manufactured to be fast/ is fast out of the box. "Stays fast" just means that the phone won't slow down.